# adding namespaces to org.apache.camel.model.language.ExpressionDefinition.xpath(), default namespace doesn't work

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, namespaces, apache-camel

I have a problem with xpath and its namespaces. 
I have soap message like follows:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <incident xmlns="some default namespace"
        xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" 
        xmlns:ns3="some namespace">
        <Company type="String">Test</Company>
    </incident>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and I need to provide xpath that compares company name with another string.
My xpath is `"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/incident[Company='Test']"` and I use it inside this part of code:

```soap
org.apache.camel.model.language.ExpressionDefinition.xpath("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/incident[Company='Test']",
                    beans.Xpath.createXpathNamespaces())
```

method Xpath().createXpathNamespaces() creates necessary namespaces:

```xpath
    public static Namespaces createXpathNamespaces() {
        Namespaces namespaces = new Namespaces(Namespaces.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE, "some default namespace");
        namespaces.add("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        namespaces.add("xmime", "http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime");
        namespaces.add("ns3", "some namespace");
    return namespaces;
}
```

and here's the problem.
When soap doesn't contains this part (default namespace): `xmlns="some default namespace"` everything works great; xpath returns true when `Company=specified name` or false when `Test!=specified name` but when default namespace is added to soap xpath return always false.
Did I something wrong or is other way to add to xpath default namespaces? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFAULT_NAMESPACE` is defined as follows:

```
Namespaces.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring";
```

So, adding this namespace is not what you want:

`Namespaces namespaces = new Namespaces(Namespaces.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE, "some default namespace");`

### Option 1: SOAP message without a namespace

If you remove the (default) namespace from the SOAP message:

```
<incident>
```

and use the XPath expression without any namespace declaration for `incident` and `Company` then this will match:

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/incident[Company='Test']
```

### Option 2: SOAP message with a namespace

However, if you want to add a namespace declaration to the SOAP message for `incident` and `Company`:

```
<incident xmlns="some default namespace">
```

then you need to add a namespace prefix for the XPath expression as well. With

```
Namespaces namespaces = new Namespaces("ns", "some default namespace");
```

you can use:

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns:incident[ns:Company='Test']
```

It doesn't matter if it is a *default* namespace or if you declare an *explicit* namespace in the SOAP message, in both cases you need to add the namespace to the XPath expression.